# Binding in RadRichTextBox (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I read some threads on telerik forum and here on this topic and I produced the following code in  xaml:

```
 <Grid>           
     <telerik:XamlDataProvider x:Name="XamlDataProvider" Xaml="{Binding xxx}"
          RichTextBox="{Binding ElementName=RadRichTextBox}"/>
     <telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="RadRichTextBox" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="False"/>
     <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding xxx}"></TextBlock>-->
</Grid>
```

The xxx is a string property in my view model which has xaml string of RadRichTextBox Document. The data from RadRichTextBox document I convert to xaml and save in database and when I open a window I want to display it in RadRichTextBox. Now it's don't work. When I uncomment the line with textblock then in it there is the xaml string so datacontex should be good.

Comment: I fixed problem by that:
<Grid>           
                                <telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="RadRichTextBox" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="False" telerik:XamlDataProvider.Source="{Binding xxx}"/>
                            </Grid>

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, please post it as an answer and then accept it once you are able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="RadRichTextBox" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="False" telerik:XamlDataProvider.Source="{Binding xxx}" />
```

It fixed my problem